# Power series coming from linear function in $\ell_3^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

**The Problem**

Suppose that $f\in \ell_3^*$. Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(e_n)^3$ converges.

**Discussion**
This problem is on a practice exam I have for a linear analysis course. My first thought on solving this question was to show that the series $(f(e_k))_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ was an element of $\ell_3$, using the fact that $f$ was a bounded linear functional. In particular, I thought I would be able to construct an element $x_N=\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_ne_n$ in $\ell_3$ with $\|x_N\|_3\leq 1$ such that $f(x_N)=\sum_{n=1}^N|f(e_n)|^3$ (or at least up to some constant not depending on $N$). We would then have

$$\sum_{n=1}^N|f(e_n)|^3=|f(x_N)|\leq \|f\|\cdot \|x_N\|_3 \leq \|f\|. $$
Taking the limit, the proof would be complete. I thought at least some variant of this argument would work, but I have had no success over the course of a few hours now. If anyone has any suggestions or hints it would be greatly appreciated : )

Comment: What do you know about the space $\ell_3^{\ast}$?

Comment: It is complete, it should also be isometric to $\ell_{3/2}$

Comment: The latter is quite useful. So if you identify $f$ with the corresponding sequence in $\ell_{3/2}$, to what do the $f(e_n)$ correspond?

Comment: The correspondence maps $f\in \ell_3^*$ to the sequence $(f(e_n))$, from this it follows immediately that the series converges (provided the isometry has already been established). We actually skipped the part in class where we proved that if $(f(e_n))$ would belong to $\ell_q$ if $f\in \ell_p^*$ (with $1/p+1/q=1$). So I will have to think about that more

Comment: If you remember the proof of Hölder's inequality, that could guide you proving that $(f(e_n))$ belongs to $\ell_q$ (and that the correspondence is an isometry).

Comment: That is more than enough to help me, thanks a lot!